# JavaScript Array vs. Object with Large Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, hashtable

I am trying to sum prime numbers under a given limit using a sieve of eratosthenes approach.  To compare the use of an array and object for storing data/performing this, I wrote two functions.  I have found that the sieve portion of the object function takes way longer than the sieve portion of the array function.  Why is this?  Is there some fundamental feature of the underlying structure of objects that I do not understand maybe?

```
function sumOfPrimesUsingArray(limit) {
    var primeArray = [],
        i,
        j,
        sum;

    //Crete array filled with values
    for (i = 2; i < limit; i += 1) {
        primeArray[i] = i;
    }

    //Perform the sieve
    for (i = 2; i < limit; i += 1) {
        if (primeArray[i] !== 0) {
            for (j = primeArray[i] + primeArray[i]; j < limit; j += primeArray[i]) {
               primeArray[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //Sum with a loop 
    sum = 0;
    for (i = 2; i < limit; i += 1) {
        sum += primeArray[i];
    }


    return sum;
}
```

And the object version of the code...

```
function sumOfPrimesUsingObject(limit) {
    var primeObject = {},
        i,
        j,
        sum,
        primes;

    //Create object filled with values 
    for (i = 2; i < limit; i += 1) {
        primeObject[i] = i;
    }

    //Perform the sieve (takes forever)
    for (i = 2; i < limit; i += 1) {
        if (primeObject[i] !== undefined) {
            for (j = primeObject[i] + primeObject[i]; j < limit; j += primeObject[i]) {
                delete primeObject[j];
            }
        }
    }

    //Sum with a loop
    sum = 0;
    for (primes in primeObject) {
        if (primeObject.hasOwnProperty(primes)) {
            sum += primeObject[primes];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Are you essentially asking why arrays are more efficient than objects for consecutive numeric indexes?  Are you surprised at this?  Wouldn't it be likely that arrays are better at what they were specifically designed to do than the more general purpose object?

Comment: Arrays are optimized for integer indices. `delete`ing properties is very costly. Try another run with `primeObject[j] = undefined` instead.

Comment: Well, arrays are definitely the best option. Still, the operations you are using are different. Here is an optimized example with objects, you will see that the difference is 1.5-2 times :http://jsfiddle.net/pfn1knmn/

Comment: Ah, thanks @juvian  It is helpful to see this!

Comment: Only problem with using sieve is memory, so after a while you would need to use another method

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript arrays are objects:

```
typeof [] === "object" //true
```

So no, you aren't missing anything language-wise.

Probably the optimization comes from the runtime as opposed to being a result of an inproper use of the datastructures.